# Counting DOM elements with CSS - not working consistently

Tags: css, css-counter

As part of some performance testing, I want to see how many DOM elements there are within a page at any given time.

Initially I used the console and manually typed: `document.getElementsByTagName('*').length`

But being that elements are dynamically added and removed, I wanted a way to show this automatically without having to do this manually.

Using CSS counters seemed to be the easiest way for me to do this:

(Here's a demo: see the yellow box in the top right)

```css
html {
    counter-reset: elems;
    counter-increment: elems;
}
html * {
  counter-increment: elems;
}
body:after {
    content: counter(elems) ' elements';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 1000000000; /* make sure display appears on top */
}
```

```html
html + head + body = 3... + 
A section with 4 divs = 5..... 3 + 5 = 8
<section>
  <div>div1</div>
  <div>div2
    <div>div3</div>
  </div> 
  <div>div4</div>
<section>
```

The problem is that this technique is not working for some more complex websites, and i'm guessing that it's because it's somehow naive.

Take for instance [wikipedia's main page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) - I used the browser inspector to add the above css-counter css and that produced "888 elements"

However when I used the console `document.getElementsByTagName('*').length` - it returned 975 elements.

**So my question is:**

What is causing this huge discrepancy in the number of DOM elements, is there something I haven't taken into account?

Can this be done reliably with CSS?

Comment: Why not update the content of element using js interval? place one div that you want to contain the number and update the content like once every 500ms

Comment: @TaufikAkbar Yes, that's something like what I'll do if I can't do this with CSS

Comment: Can you try the JS on the html page with empty body and bunch of meta tags? because if I changed the rule to `html head * { counter-increment: elems; }` it displays 0

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get different counts is because your `counter-increment: elems;` rule is lower priority than some existing `counter-increment` rules in Wikipedia's stylesheet, so there are elements which increment other counters (one example is named "listitem") but not yours.

You'd have to make your selector more specific and override Wikipedia's, or add the website's own counter (or write some JavaScript to add your own counter in the existing `counter-increment` rules, to avoid breaking the existing style).

Comment: it seems that even if i set it to !important in browser style editor, the number is still the same

Comment: Did you try this successfully?

Comment: ah, you're right, it's not just the other counter-increments

Comment: @Touffy I think css `*` will ignore tags such as meta, link, style, script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> What is causing this huge discrepancy in the number of DOM elements,
>   is there something I haven't taken into account?

Yes, elements which have `display:none` applied are ignored by css counters.

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#counters-without-boxes):

> An element that does not generate a box (for example, an element with
>   display set to none, or a pseudo-element with content set to none)
>   cannot set, reset, or increment a counter. The counter properties are
>   still valid on such an element, but they must have no effect.

**Demo:**

```css
html {
    counter-reset: elems;
    counter-increment: elems; /* Include the html element as well */
}
html * {
  counter-increment: elems;
}
body:after {
    content: counter(elems) ' elements';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0.3rem;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    z-index: 1000000000; /* make sure display appears on top */
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
html + head + body = 3... + 
A section with 4 divs = 5..... 3 + 5 = 8
<section>
  <div>div1</div>
  <div>div2
    <div>div3</div>
  </div> 
  <div>div4</div>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
<section>
```

On the other hand `document.getElementsByTagName('*').length` WILL count elements with `display:none`

This may only be one of the differences which I hadn't taken into account, but I'd say it's probably the main culprit as to the discrepancy.